Does physicalism in philosophy accept the concept of God as the notion of supervenience?

The word "physicalism" was introduced into philosophy in the 1930s by
Otto Neurath and Rudolf Carnap.[6]
The use of "physical" in physicalism is a philosophical concept and
can be distinguished from alternative definitions found in the
literature (e.g., Karl Popper defined a physical proposition as one
that can at least in theory be denied by observation[7]). A "physical
property", in this context, may be a metaphysical or logical
combination of properties which are physical in the ordinary sense. It
is common to express the notion of "metaphysical or logical
combination of properties" using the notion of supervenience: A
property A is said to supervene on a property B if any change in A
necessarily implies a change in B.[8] Since any change in a
combination of properties must consist of a change in at least one
component property, we see that the combination does indeed supervene
on the individual properties. The point of this extension is that
physicalists usually suppose the existence of various abstract
concepts which are non-physical in the ordinary sense of the word; so
physicalism cannot be defined in a way that denies the existence of
these abstractions. Also, physicalism defined in terms of
supervenience does not entail that all properties in the actual world
are type identical to physical properties. It is therefore compatible
with multiple realizability.[9]
David Papineau[17] and Barbara Montero[18] have advanced and
subsequently defended[19] a "via negativa" characterization of the
physical. The gist of the via negativa strategy is to understand the
physical in terms of what it is not: the mental. In other words, the
via negativa strategy understands the physical as "the non-mental". An
objection to the via negativa conception of the physical is that (like
the object-based conception) it lacks the resources to distinguish
neutral monism (or panprotopsychism) from physicalism.[20] Further,
Restrepo argues that this conception of the physical makes core
non-physical entities of non-physicalist metaphysics, like God,
Cartesian souls and abstract numbers, physical, and thus either false
or trivially true: "God is non-mentally-and-non-biologically
identifiable as the thing that created the universe. Supposing
emergentism is true, non-physical emergent properties are
non-mentally-and-non-biologically identifiable as non-linear effects
of certain arrangements of matter. The immaterial Cartesian soul is
non-mentally-and-non-biologically identifiable as one of the things
that interact causally with certain particles (coincident with the
pineal gland). The Platonic number eight is
non-mentally-and-non-biologically identifiable as the number of
planets orbiting the Sun".[21]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicalism#:~:text=8%20External%20links-,Definition%20of%20physicalism%20in%20philosophy,Otto%20Neurath%20and%20Rudolf%20Carnap.

I am trying to understand what wiki says on the subject, but cannot get a formulation of a reasonable answer.

Your selective quoting from the Wikipedia page shows that you are interested in Papineau’s via negativa as a characterisation of physicalism, so my answer will focus on that.  There are a few things to unpack here: The via negativa characterisation is not mainstream physicalism but an attempt to redefine physicalism by using Hempel’s dilemma. Reductive physicalism holds on to physical closure: physical effects have only physical causes.
Now, Hempel’s dilemma says that reductive physicalism is not a good framework because it can not conclusively say what is physical and what is not, based on (1) the incompleteness of present day physics or (2) an idealized version of physics that does not exist yet. In other words: what is physical is not exactly understood and this closes the door to non-physical entities (like God) in the light of present day physics, though it might be included in a physical description of the universe once we have a complete understanding of physics at some time in the future. Either way, this is not satisfactory, because clearly mental entities exists, but they can not be included in a physicalist description of the world with physical closure.
The via negativa is a physicalism that holds on to physical closure, but to avoid Hempel’s dilemma, the via negativa tries to define physicalism in terms of what it is not: the non-mental. It then maintains that the non-mental is also non-mentally closed. That means non-mental effects have only non-mental causes. In my understanding this is an attempt to smuggle God into physicalism: so far we couln’t include God in physicalism because in our current understanding we have no way to describe God in physical terms. But by defining physicalism as a description of the world with the non-mental, the via negativa leaves the door open that God could be somehow, somewhere, in the gray area between the physical and the non-mental.
For good measure, conventional physicalism, that is, as it is normally understood, leaves no room for God, so no, physicalism doesn't accept that physics supervenes on God. One more thing: supervenience is subtly different from reduction and I am not sure if supervenience is pertinent to Hempel's dilemma.

Thank you for your in-depth explanation. I feel less confused by these conflicting methodologies trying to define physicalism as a philosophical theory describing our reality.

Hempel’s dilemma presupposes that the non-physical is a coherent and meaningful category, and that physicalism is drawing a line to exclude it. Physicalism has the physical being all that there is and everything being physical (including consciousness), so it seems unlikely that the dilemma would be a dilemma under that view. One might draw an analogy to atheism: atheists don't accept any god claims, particularly conscious creator deities, and those of known religions. Hempel’s dilemma is comparable to saying "what if we define this cup to be god" - it is itself a redefinition.

@NotThatGuy Totally agree. But to steelman Hempel's dilemma (not my view), it holds that the current state of physics has no way to reduce mental events to physical events because it is not complete. To say that future physics will be able to do that is void, because it will by definition render everything physical and is thus meaningless.  I don't think Hempel's dilemma has anything to say about God. For good measure, I am just explaining other people's philosophy...

@Philomath Whether future physics can explain it is largely irrelevant. Hempel’s dilemma presupposes that there are 2+ categories of things (physical and non-physical), and says physicalism draws a poorly-defined line that excludes one. But physicalism only posits that there is 1 category of things (physical). If someone wants to posit that there are 2 categories, it would be on them to explain what those categories are and differentiate and justify them. Putting that on physicalists is shifting the burden of proof, by asking them to make sense of the non-physical claims they don't accept.

@NotThatGuy I told you that it's got nothing to do with claims physicalists don't accept (God). It's about mental events and about reductive physicalism. If you believe that consciousness exist then you have to reduce it to the physical.

@Philomath Can we not say that a distant star exists, if we do not know its exact physical consistency? Saying that one cannot reject the non-physical unless one is able to provide a full reduction of everything single thing in the universe - that seems to place an unreasonable burden of proof on physicalists, and it's still shifting the burden of proof. It's like saying you can't reject the existence of a teapot orbiting the Sun unless one is able to account for every molecule in the Solar System.

@NotThatGuy Look, I am as hardcore as they come in atheism, physicalism and hard determinism, but I do indeed think that you have to prove reduction of the mental to the physical.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your title question doesn't really have much to do with your quote. But no, supervenience and God are completely different concepts that don't have much to do with each other.
Here's an example of supervenience. I have a coffee cup that's three inches tall. The property of the cup being three inches tall supervenes on the arrangement of atoms of the cup - because any change in the cup's height must be simultaneous with a change in the arrangement of atoms. There's nothing particularly theistic about the height of a coffee cup.
Also, supervenience is not limited to physicalism; dualists and others can make use of the concept just as well.

I understand the concept of atoms. But (according to wiki) physical objects have metaphysical supervenience. Then, God created atoms?

Supervenience on what? I would argue that atoms supervene on the existing quantum fields and nothing more. God is not, strictly speaking, necessary.
